# I am getting `getAddrInfo ENOTFOUND localhost` on running simple node server even though localhost is present in /etc/hosts (MacOS El Capitan)

Tags: node.js, dns, osx-elcapitan

I have a very weird thing happening while setting up and running a normal node js server.

When I run `node server.js`, I get following error:

```
Server running at http://localhost:1337/
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
       at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

When I open `http://localhost:1337/` in my browser, it says `page does not exist`.

When I run `sudo node server.js`, it runs fine without any error and I can access my site at `https://localhost:1337`

Here is my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

My server.js:

```
// Require what we need
var http = require("http");
// Build the server
var app = http.createServer(function(request, response {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    });
response.end("Hello world!\n");
});
// Start that server, baby
app.listen(1337, "localhost");
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:1337/");
```

**Other Details**

1. OS: Mac OS (El Capitan)
2. Node JS version: 6.10.3 (installed globally)
3. NPM version: 4.5.0 (installed globally)

**Following are my questions**

1. Why is the above server.js file working with admin access but not as a normal user?
2. Does globally installed node only work with admin access?
3. Is there anything else in Mac OS which can affect DNS lookup other than /etc/hosts? I have already flushed my DNS cache and reboot my OS just to make sure that older DNS lookup is not being used.

Comment: Next time ask only 1 question per topic.

Comment: @Luuklag sure. I will take care of this from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this same error by editing the file `/etc/hosts`

Added the lines:

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue and have been able to solve it also by removing this IPv6 line. Do you have any idea why having this line in hosts file causes these issues?